# CSS Double background in IE 7,8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

I have next div with 2 background images,
But images are not visible in IE 7 and 8.

```
 <div class="media" style="background-image: url('/play_video.png'), url('/video.jpg')">
                        <span>Click to play video</span>
                    </div>

.media {    
    background-position: center, center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:245px;    
    height:150px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;             
}
    .media span {        
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        color: black;
    }
```

is it possible to fix ?

Comment: clever use of multiple divs and z-index can make a similar effect. Bigger question is why bother supporting IE7 or 8?

Answer (score 3):

Nether IE7 nor 8 support multiple background images. [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

For the sake of the community, [here's a workaround using positioning](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/fnIsz).

**HTML**

```
<div class="media-back">
  <span>Click to play</span>
  <div class="media-play">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.media-back {
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQIbNF1wUNRvdk13BTlt_KZ6HrspnBIpMIOXAkbHsioDTCxMT5r);
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
.media-play {
  position:relative;
  background-image:url(http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png);
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  width:15%;
  height:15%;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
span {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

It's not finessed and I don't know what aesthetic you're going for, but you can fake the same effect using positioning.

Comment: Providing a workaround would make this answer a bit more useful maybe

Comment: [Here is a more reputable source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) ;) - with a fixed link

Comment: And not linking [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: It's a legit answer. You cannot "fix" the background image property of IE7/8, but you can use styling workarounds. I agree with @Kai-Quing above, though...why support IE7 or 8?

Comment: @BrianBennett - This answer would be well served by stating that the best idea is for IE 7 and 8 to gracefully degrade... Make sure they look acceptable with one background and move on.

Comment: if it helps to know, I usually use modernizr and add a .no-csstransitions css selector to handle lesser IE specific overrides. But typically I write the css to not require this at all. None the less, sometimes the design calls for it. I see nothing wrong with this answer. I don't think it needs a work around per say. It's like asking how to get flash to work on an iphone. It don't work, so move on.